# Word Automation search in range

Tags: automation, ms-word, find, range

This is how I define the find object:

```
    Range rngDoc = m_oDocument.GetContent();
    nEnd = rngDoc.GetEnd();
    rngDoc.SetRange(nStart,nEnd);//do not search entire document -> faster
    Find fn = rngDoc.GetFind();
```

However, when I execute the Find, it finds objects that lay before the given start.
Any idea how do I define where the find should search?

Comment: what word automation search is this ?, and what language is the code written in ? it'll be betteroff, if you could add somemore context to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

Problem was that the start of the Range was in a table cell and the end was the end of the document. For some reason, Find then searches entire cell, and not from the beginning of the range.

EDIT: It seems that problem occurs whenever there is a table in the range. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Great. You can accept your own answer (click the checkmark next to this) as the correct answer.